# Check if layer of multipoint is contained in a Polygon in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

As the question says, I want to check if the points are contained in a polygon.
[image: check]

So far, I tried `containsPoint` but it returns undefined.

```
var p = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13977549.20, 1019860.15);
for (var i = 0; i < layer_floodhazard.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = layer_floodhazard.features[i];
    var inside = feature.geometry.containsPoint(p);
    if (inside) {
        alert('Contains');
    };
}
```

`layer_floodhazard` is a vector layer added on the map. On the other hand, I have another vector layer which contains points in which I am trying to check if those points are within or the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

The containsPoint function should never return undefined:

> {Boolean | Number} The point is inside the polygon.  Returns 1 if the point is on an edge.  Returns boolean otherwise.

so you are probably not calling the containsPoint function you think you are.

I would put a breakpoint on the line that calls containsPoint, and inspect the 'feature' object, to ensure you're calling the function on the correct property.  I expect it's .geometry property is not an OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon object.

Without knowing how the layer_floodhazard.features array was populated there is no way of knowing without seeing some working code.  If you could put your code into a plunker or similar service I'd be happy to help you debug.

Additionally, just checking for 'truthyness' may not give you the desired results as objects on the edge will also be considered 'inside' based on your test.  I would test for (result === true) to ensure you're checking for the boolean true result returned if the point is inside the polygon.  Of course that's not related to your current problem :).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I do realize now that `layer_floodhazard` has no containsPoint function on it when I looked at the documentation. Actually, it a vector layer.

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you with your problem, thanks!